# how do i cache FileContentResult for performance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, firefox, caching

Presently i have the following action to return files (images, PDF's, etc) from my DB:

```
    //
    // GET: /FileManager/GetFile/ID
    [OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "ID")]
    public ActionResult GetFile(int ID)
    {
        FileService svc = new FileService(new SqlFileRepository(base.ConnectionString));

        KsisOnline.Data.File result = svc.GetFileByID(ID);

        return File(result.Data, result.MimeType, result.UploadFileName);
    }
```

I'm using the `OutputCache` attribute but i dont know if i'm using it correctly or how to optimise it for this purpose.

As the code stands, i appear to get cache functionality in Firefox(3) but not IE(7). For some reason IE is requesting the image from the DB every time (which is killer bad obviously) and i dont know how to fix it. Sure IE doesn't support standards properly but maybe i'm still not following some preferred caching conventions. I'd really appreciate some help with this so i get minimal DB hits and caching support cross browser.

**EDIT:**
To see the code above in action or to profile it yourself with browsers/tools, refer to [this link](http://ksis.sch.sa/Announcements/56).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How return 304 status with FileResult in ASP.NET MVC RC1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602104/how-return-304-status-with-fileresult-in-asp-net-mvc-rc1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what HTTP headers are sent by IE and your applications how these are different from ones for Firefox. What you have to have is to make browser send `If-Modified-Since` header (and possibly an `ETag`) header and your app should respond with HTTP 302 status.

Comment: i was kinda hoping to get the help with the OutputCacheAttribute specifics 1st. but your suggestion will be invaluable in optimizing the HTTP headers. thanx

Comment: @Anton Don't you mean "respond with HTTP *304* status"? 302 is a redirect

Answer (score 5):

Try use ServerAndClient location:

[OutputCache(Duration=600, VaryByParam="ID", Location=OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]

Answer (score 0):

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.ClearHeaders()
```