# Bizzare HttpWebResponse Error: ServerProtocolViolation

Tags: c#, mono, httpwebrequest, xamarin.ios, httpwebresponse

I have tried everything and I can not figure out why this error happens.

**Background**:
I have an IPad application, written in MonoTouch and I have a thread that runs in the background, and every 15 seconds I sync data with the server. This works the first few iterations of the thread, but eventually I get the following stack trace.

```
An exception occured: System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone4): ServerProtocolViolation ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
  at System.UInt32.Parse (System.String s) [0x00010] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/UInt32.cs:405 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.GetResponse (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 max) [0x000ba] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:565 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone (IAsyncResult result) [0x00095] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:446 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:819 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:827 
  at SyncService.REST.RestClient.Execute[IEnumerable`1] (SyncService.REST.RestRequest request) [0x00079] in /Users/Chris/Compass/SyncService/REST/RestClient.cs:42
```

I am talking to an **IIS webserver** with default configuration.
Here is the method I am calling:

```
public RestResponse<T> Execute<T>(RestRequest request){
    var restResponse = new RestResponse<T>();
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var urlPath = _baseUrl + "/" + request.Resource;
    var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(urlPath));

    httpRequest.Headers = request.Headers;
    Authenticator.Authenticate(httpRequest);

    httpRequest.Method = request.Method.ToString();
    if (request.Method == Method.POST)
        SetPostData(httpRequest, request);

    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;
    try{
        httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpRequest.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
        var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        restResponse.StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;
        restResponse.Headers = httpResponse.Headers;
        restResponse.Data = serializer.Deserialize<T>(responseString);
        restResponse.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.Completed;
    } 
    catch(WebException e){

        restResponse.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.Error;
        restResponse.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        restResponse.ErrorException = e;
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) e.Response;
        if (webResponse != null){
            restResponse.StatusCode = webResponse.StatusCode;
            restResponse.Headers = webResponse.Headers;
        }
        if (restResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occured: " + e + "\r\n");
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        restResponse.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.Error;
        restResponse.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        restResponse.ErrorException = ex;
    }

    if (httpResponse != null) 
        httpResponse.Close();

    return restResponse;
}
```

Please help. I don't know what to do. Google shows nothing.

**I am able to make 22 successful requests before the error shows up.**

**EDIT**
I have narrowed it down to being a server issue. This is asp.net MVC and the exception only happens when I send a 304 to the client. See Server Code:

```
private void ServeHttpStatusCode() {
    Response.StatusCode = 304;
    Response.Status = "304 Not Modified";
    Response.StatusDescription = "The resource you are requesting has not been modified";
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Response.Write("{\"Error\":\"The resource you are requesting has not been modified\"}");
    Response.End();
    Response.Close();
}
```

Comment: It means the server is not acting nicely :) Can you use a HTTP sniffer like Fiddler or Ethereal to see what the raw response is?

Comment: Its working 22 times, then stops. If I kill my app and start over...all is good for another 22 requests. You still think its on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is there a proxy between the client
  and the server?
- Does it always fail after 22 requests?
  The exception indicates that some UInt32 can't be parsed.
- Do you get exceptions on the server side?

Comment: No proxy, approximately 22 requests and no server exceptions.

Comment: Can you show the client code? You could be mistakenly re-using some thing on the client side.

Comment: Considering the exception and the 304 status code, best guess is to remove any descriptive text in that case.

Comment: Remove Response.Write. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602104/how-return-304-status-with-fileresult-in-asp-net-mvc-rc1/602235#602235

Comment: It had to do with the content type, I set that to null and all is well. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is scouring the internet looking for answers on this issue, I had a very similar problem with some functional tests I was writing. They were uploading content to a webserver using http PUT and then using http GET straight after.

The GET failed reliably with the same error in the Uint32 parse. The windows build was fine. In desperation I used Thread.Sleep(20) to insert some delay between http requests, and this has cleared up the error. Not sure why, but it works now, which is good enough for my tests, if not for production stuff.